# How can I find out if numbers can be made equal in an array using this?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This question was given to me in an interview and I couldn't really come up with a solution for this:

If I am given an array containing some numbers, and I can double or triple each of the numbers an infinite number of times, and I just have to find out if the numbers can be made equal to each other or not, how can I do it? What can be a possible algorithm for this?

Comment: What does it mean 'can be _made equal_'?

Comment: That is, if all the elements in the array can be made equal after the performed operation.

Comment: So you can use `* 2` and `* 3` on each element of the array any number of times?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about providing a solution to an interview question.

Comment: @jeffrey, yes. We can do it any number of times.

Comment: `I just have to find out if the numbers can be made equal or not` equal to what?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious That's on topic (algorithms are perfectly fine here). You can close due to lack of research though, as the question does not show any effort made to solve it before asking.

Comment: @amit, equal to each other or not.

Comment: I think it's not possible. Let's take `a` and `b` as start numbers, and look if we can find `n`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` such that `n = a * 2^i * 3^j = b * 2^k * 3^l`. Then the prime factorization of `n` contains both `a` and `b`. Now, let's say `a` and `b` are both prime, and neither are `2` or `3`. It's then impossible to add one as a factor in calculating `n` from the other. Thus, there's no general solution.

Comment: @Quentin Isn´t that the question (to find out if it is possible for some array or not?) Nobody said that a solution always exist.

Comment: @deviantfan ...oh. Well maybe that comment will be of use anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take two elements from that array, and call them `a` and `b`. Now let's double and triple both of them until they're equal:

```
a * 2^i * 3^j == b * 2^m * 3^n
```

From this we can conclude that this works if (by simple transformation of above equation)

```
a / (2^m * 3^n) == b / (2^i * 3^j)
```

At first, this might not seem helpful. But remember that every number can be represented as the product of its prime factors:

```
c = 2^u * 3^v * 5^w * 7^x * 11^y * ...
(u, v, w, ... may be 0)
```

Now applying that to the previous equation, if we make `m` and `n` equal to the number of 2s and 3s (`u`and `v`) all that remains from `a` would be the product of all its prime factors expect 2 and 3. Do the same with `b` and then compare the results.

Now putting that into an algorithm (and applying it to more numbers) isn't so difficult (though we need to take care because we surely don't want to compute all prime factors of all elements).

1. Take the first element
2. Divide by `2` until it's no longer dividable by `2`
3. Same but for `3`
4. Save that as value to compare against
5. Take the next element
6. Divide by `2` as long as it's dividable by `2`
7. Same for `3`
8. Compare result to saved value, if different return `false`
9. Else, if there are elements left, GOTO 5.
10. If no elements are left, return `true`

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers aren´t huge, you could calculate the (prime) factorization for each,
remove all 2´s and 3´s, and compare the sorted rest.

Example 1:

```
Numbers: 2 12 6  
Factorization: (2) (2*2*3) (2*3)  
2 and 3 removed: () () ()  
Everything equal: Yes, so this numbers can be made equal
```

Example 2:

```
Numbers: 4 14  
Factorization: (2*2) (2*7)  
2 and 3 removed: () (7)   
Everything equal: No, so this numbers can´t be made equal
```

Basically, for each number you´re calulating the remainder if you divide it by 2 and/or 3
as often as possible. If The remainders are equal...

Comment: I don't think you need to factorize the numbers. Just work out their greatest common divisor and divide everything by that. You are OK iff all the numbers left after this are multiples only of power of two and powers of three.

Comment: Hm...right, that´s even easier :D If you post an answer, you´ll have my upvote for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)?

Answer (score 1):

Take each number in the array and remove all factors 2 and 3 from it in O(n log n). Then check if all the numbers in the array are equal.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int remove2And3(int x) {
    while(x%2==0) x/=2;
    while(x%3==0) x/=3;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    while(cin >> n) {
        int first; cin >> first; 
        first = remove2And3(first);

        bool answer = true;

        for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
            int other; cin >> other;
            other = remove2And3(other);

            answer &= first == other;
        }

        cout << (answer ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to divided every numbers until it divisible by 2 or 3 and put it on to set
and finally check set size is equal to 1 or not, if set size is 1 then **yes** otherwise **no**.

Here below is c++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int tc, num;
    std::set<int> ss;
    while (std::cin >> tc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
            std::cin >> num;
            while (num%2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
                if (num % 2 == 0)
                    num /= 2;
                else if (num % 3 == 0)
                    num /= 3;
            }
            ss.insert(num);
        }

        if (ss.size() == 1)
            std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
        ss.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line, `each item can be doubled or tripled` implies that you can multiply every number any number of times by `2` and `3`. The ramifications of this are that the prime factorization of the number won't change, except the powers of `2` and `3`. The corollary from this is that if two numbers have the same prime factorization, differing only in the powers of `2` and `3`, they can be made equal. To clarify, my interpretation of making two numbers equal is that those two numbers multiplied by different number of `2s` and `3s` can be made equal to each other.

A simple function to check this on two numbers is as follows:

```
bool check(int a, int b)
{
  while (a%2 == 0)
    a = a/2;
  while (a%3 == 0)
    a = a/3;
  while (b%2 == 0)
    b = b/2;
  while (b%3 == 0)
    b = b/3;
  return (a == b);
}
```

You can easily extend this to checking for an entire array.

Comment: I think your text sounds reasonable, but your code looks weird.  `a%2` is either 0 or 1.  Taking `a%3` of that, instead of the original `a`, adds no new information.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for that. Stupid on my part. Have fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't that common divider problem? Just see if you can find bigger number that can produce integer in division by any of given numbers.

So having {2,3,5} array you could say yes, for something like 30.

Comment: And how can eg. 3 made to 30 by multiplying 2 or 3? `3*10=30`, but 10 can´t be generated by 2 and 3.

Comment: Didn't think that was the rule used in the task, just an example. So we should wait and see what author has to say.

Answer (score -3):

Divide the element by itself from second index to last and multiply by first element.

```
Ex: array [2, 3, 4, 7, ...]

So now [2, 3/3 *2, 4/4 * 2, 7 / 7 * 2...]
```

If element is zero don't divide just add first element.